# SQL GROUP_CONCAT with LEFT JOIN to multiple relative rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been stuck on this for hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated

I have two tables 'products' and 'product_subcategorys'

'products' holds only unique ids where as 'product_subcategorys' holds multiple ids relative to the 'products' table

```
'products'
id   brand
1    a
2    b
3    a

'product_subcategorys'
id   subcat
1    u
1    i
2    u
3    u
```

this is the query I have, Group by 'p.id' doesn't appear to work

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.brand)
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_subcategorys s ON p.id = s.id
WHERE (
        s.subcategory = "u"
        OR s.subcategory = "i"
        ) AS GROUPbrand
```

So my problem is, i want it to return the list of brands only from the 'product' table I cant use distinct because i need to count the multiples

I want the query to return brand 'a' twice, but this query is returning it 3 times since there are two matching ids in the 'product_subcategorys'

Comment: Edit your question and add your desired results.  And note that the query you specify only returns one row, so I have no idea what you mean by "this query is returning it 3 tiems".

Comment: You need to count the multiples. Should these be multiple rows,or do you need numeric count?

Comment: I need return the the rows for example 'a,b,a' at the moment I'm getting 'a, a,b,a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.brand ORDER BY p.id)
FROM products p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM product_subcategorys s 
              WHERE p.id = s.id AND
                    s.subcategory IN ('u', 'i')
             );
```

Comment: Thanks so much! sorry It took me so long to test it as It was part of a long query that I had tweak all over the place. It seems to be doing the trick though!